# Retrieving public Facebook data from a user session without authentication (How does Pinterest do it?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api

If you go to [pinterest](http://pinterest.com/bikes) whilst logged into a facebook account and not logged into pinterest, it shows a list of your friends that have pinterest accounts along the top.

[image]

I'd like to build something similar to this so my question is twofold.

1. How can my site find out the facebook details of the current user if they are currently logged into facebook without them authenticating with my site? I assume I can find this in their session somehow.
2. As I understand it, facebook graph does not give you access to a users friends list until they have authenticated with you. If this is true, how are pinterest able to display all my friends that have signed up to them? Have they saved to a database everyones friends when they sign up and matched me with that list? Surely theres an easier way.

My site is written in rails so any answers relating to this would be ideal. Though I know this is more of a theory question so any help would be welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinterest is using a "Social Plugin" called Facepile. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile for an introduction.

They are also using Facebook Login (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.0), and therefore use a Facebook App and the JavaScript SDK in the frontend. This App's ID is the input parameter for the Facepile, which calls FB backend services to determine the friends of the logged-in user who are also using this specific App.

Comment: I see. I thought I would have to build it myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are using the Facebook's [**Faceplie**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/) plugin.

Example-

```
<iframe class="fbIframe" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?app_id=APPID&amp;size=small&amp;max_rows=1" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true">
</iframe>
```